# How to open only Excel files from a particular and copy particular cell values from each excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy particular cell values from all the excel files in a particular folder

Here Sheet1 is the main sheet in which i need to copy the values from other excel files
Here is my requirements,

- I need to search for all the Excel files in a particular folder.
- From that folder from each excel files i need to copy, 
  D4 and paste in Sheet1 cells A,
  D5 and paste in Sheet1 cells B,
  F14:F19 and paste(transpose) in Sheet1 cells C:H.

I have the code but in this i have 3 errors which i couldn't solve

Errors which i am facing

- I couldn't paste the values of Highlighted cells from all the excel files
- It is taking more time where if i have more than 100 files, their is changes for excel to go to "Not Responding" State
- If i don't have any values in any of the cell means it would over lap other value , i need to overcome with this.

Below is the excel File
https://app.box.com/s/cflde3s87qkj11c69vyfv0h5ur9n4bpq

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object

Dim file, Folder, Fname As Variant
Dim wbThis                  As Workbook
Dim wbTarget                As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Dim vDB, vDB1, vDB2, vDB3, vDB4, vDB5, vDB6, vDB7 As Variant

Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
Set sht1 = wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1")

Folder = Cells(2, "J").Value & "\"
Fname = Dir(Folder & "*.xls*")

While (Fname <> "")

  Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Folder & Fname)

  vDB = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("D4")
  vDB1 = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("D5")
  vDB2 = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("F14")
  vDB3 = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("F15")
  vDB4 = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("F16")
  vDB5 = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("F17")
  vDB6 = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("F18")
  vDB7 = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("F19")

        sht1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) = vDB
        sht1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) = vDB1
        sht1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) = vDB2
        sht1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) = vDB3
        sht1.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) = vDB4
        sht1.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) = vDB5
        sht1.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) = vDB6
        sht1.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) = vDB7

 Fname = Dir

  wbTarget.Close
 Wend

End Sub
```

I expect the output as it should open all the excel files and copy the required fields to the desired destination

Any suggestions/Solutions could help me a lot

Regards,
Dhruva

Comment: what is the value of the variable Folder ? are there xls* files in there ?

Comment: Yes their are xls* files in that folder

Comment: add `msgbox folder & " " & fname` as first instruction in the while loop to check the content.

Comment: possible reasons why you have nothing. Folder is empty, or Folder doesn't contain xls* files, or xls* files do not contain any value in the specified cells.